# Como criar a partir de uma nuvem de pontos polígonos côncavos?

Tags: python, matemática, geometria

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de criar polígonos não convexo a partir de uma nuvem de pontos.
Vou dar um exemplo com alguns poucos pontos, mas a ideia é que eu possa gerar um código que me retorne o polígono/envoltória a partir de uma nuvem de pontos.
No exemplo abaixo eu gero o polígono, mas gostaria que o código não me retornasse o ponto (15,13) pois é um ponto que estaria dentro do polígono

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon = Polygon([(10, 10), (10, 20), (15,15) ,(15,13),(15,15),(20, 20),(20, 10)])

print (polygon)

polygon
```

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se uma geometria é valida com a propriedade [`object.is_valid`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.is_valid). Um polígono válido não pode ter nenhum [anel](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linearrings) externo ou interno sobreposto e seus anéis também devem ser válidos ou seja um anel não pode se cruzar e não pode se tocar em nenhum ponto.

Caso o polígono não seja válido use o método [`object.buffer()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) com o parâmetro `distance` igual a `0` para computar uma representação aproximada dos pontos do objeto geométrico.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

pp = Polygon([(10, 10), (10, 20), (15,15) ,(15,13),(15,15),(20, 20),(20, 10)])

if not pp.is_valid:
  print(f"Poligono {pp} inválido.")
  pp = pp.buffer(0)
  print(f"Representação aproximada {pp}")
  

pp
```

[image: Resultado]

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1r7da9X0S8RnL5PLzyWlstNwiDqHRLpGR?usp=sharing)</sup>